# How do you beat the Grandmaster Galaxy in SMG2?

Tags: nintendo-wii, super-mario-galaxy-2

I've been stuck on the Grandmaster Galaxy for a couple years now. I can make it to the Boomerang Bros., where the goal is nearly in sight, but I can't make it past them.

How do I get past them?

Comment: In Super Mario Galaxy 2, Grandmaster Galaxy beat *you*!

Answer (score 4):

If you can't beat the Boomerang Bros. straight-up, there are a few tricks you can try:

- Have Player 2 poke them a bit. Even having just one of them out of sync with the other two significantly decreases the number of stuff you have to dodge at once.
- Duck. Boomerangs can't hit you when you're crouching, so you can easily crawl up to one guy and smack him.

Answer (score 2):

Practice, practice, pratice.

If I rememeber correctly, there are six parts.  Before I tried to tackle the entire galaxy under Daredevil Run conditions, I practiced each part in normal mode until I could do them pretty consistently without dying/getting touched.  That way, I had my whole route mapped out when it was time to do the Daredevil Run.

That being said, crouching when you get to the Boomerang Bros. was a *revelation* when I saw someone do it on a video. Crucial tactic.  Also, pause the game and dry your nervous, sweaty, hands off.

Comment: Practicing on non-Daredevil is a great idea I hadn't thought of. So much more efficient than repeating the easy sections to get to the hard section.

Answer (score 1):

On the Daredevil run, you just run for it in the beginning. Then at the blue star part, you hold the star for about 1.5 seconds, then let go. You will go further than the star itself. Keep using that tactic until the Boomerang Bros. part. If you have 2 players, make the 2nd player hold the Boomerang Bros. You have to do the "leap" to get across to each block. If you are 1 player, crouch every time you see a Boomerang Bro about to throw the boomerang.Leap to every block at just the right timing. Then you will reach a launch star, instead of the normal Power star. launch yourself, and you will use cloud power to get the final Power star. Then you will see Rosalina and the whole ending.